# Multiple Push Certificates for one Bundle ID

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have searched around and couldn't find a clear answer. Does anybody know of a potential issue with having multiple (2-3) APNS certificates for the same bundle Id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will not have any issue with multiple APNS certificates. However, it will become clumsy if you have more than 2 certificates.

Comment: Certainly clumsy. thanks for the reply. If anybody feels additionally confident in this please let me know!